# Azure SQL DTU Consumption 100% Behaviour

Tags: sql, azure, consumption

I have a more general question to which I unfortunately could not find anything documentated in the offical azure sql db ressources. What is the behaviour of the Azure SQL once I am reaching a DTU Consumption of above 100%?

For example writing constantly entries into a table although having already hitten the DTU consumption of 100% ? Do incoming entries get a timeout or a queued in someway?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

At DTU max, queries begin being queued. As the queue length builds, queries may time out. This is a reason why retry logic is important in case your database gets temporarily hammered and this situation occurs.